# (TRIGGER) if cell1 = 'value' THEN INSERT INTO table (date) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server that triggers every time that the value from column "status" = 'Baja'

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_triggerName 
ON dbo.table1 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF status = 'Baja' THEN BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (fechaBaja)  
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    END
END
GO
```

I got this error message

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_FechaBaja, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 34]
>   Invalid column name 'status'.

```
     IF status = 'Baja' THEN BEGIN
```

In this line the "status" give me the message "invalid column name 'status'" and I'm 100% sure that my column has that name.

IN RESUME: Got a table named table1 that has a column named 'status'  and another column named 'fechaBaja'

Every time that the 'status' value changes to 'Baja', I need to trigger and update the cell 'fechaBaja' with the `current_timestamp`

All the operations are in the same `table1`.

Comment: Yes you have that column, but where and which row, INSERTED table? DELETED table? Table1? You need to check `INSERTED` table there. Please explain what are you trying to do there

Comment: also status is a reserved word... so it's best to enclose it in brackets or not use it as a column name at all

Comment: hi @Sami, it is on table1, all the operation in fact. about the row, does this mean that everytime I perform this operation all the rows could be affected ?

Comment: @HiramL. Since your trigger is fired _AFTER UPDATE_ you need to check `INSERTED` table not `dbo.table1`, and also you need to change you code to handle multiple rows. I suggest that you edit your question and add the DDL of your table and explain what are trying to do there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to update fechaBaja field if updated row status field equal'Baja'. You need to capture primary key information as well. I put 'Id' but you need to change it with your actuel field name.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trg_triggerName ON dbo.table1 
 AFTER UPDATE AS
 BEGIN

        UPDATE dbo.table1 SET fechaBaja=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED I WHERE dbo.table1.Id = I.Id AND I.Status='Baja')

 END
 GO
```

Comment: you are right @Sami. I have updated the trigger to cover multiple update.

Comment: @ZekiGumus  thank you for your help, this  TRIGGER works perfectly, now I'm having trouble because I have another AFTER UPDATE trigger for this table that affects other column, but thanks man, this was I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

First, you want an `update`, not an `insert`.

Second, A trigger in SQL Server is fired once per statement, not once per row. This means that if the update statement that fired the trigger have updated multiple rows, your trigger will be fired once, and include data about these rows in the `inserted` and `deleted` tables.

Third, You need to make sure that the update statement inside the trigger will not raise it again. Do that by configuring the database.

The code you need is something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trg_triggerName ON dbo.table1 
     AFTER UPDATE AS
 BEGIN

     UPDATE t
     SET fechaBaja = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     FROM dbo.table1 As T
     INNER JOIN Inserted As I
         ON T.<PrimaryKey> = I.<PrimaryKey>
     INNER JOIN Deleted As D
         ON T.<PrimaryKey> = D.<PrimaryKey>
     WHERE I.[status] = 'Baja'
     AND (D.[Status] IS NULL OR D.[Status] <> 'Baja')

 END
 GO
```

Comment: You miss `)` there. `AND (D.[Status] IS NULL OR D.[Status] <> 'Baja')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by joining the three tables like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_triggerName ON dbo.table1 AFTER UPDATE AS
 BEGIN
     UPDATE T1
     SET T1.fechaBaja = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     FROM dbo.table1 T1 INNER JOIN INSERTED T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                        INNER JOIN DELETED  T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
     WHERE T2.[status] = 'Baja'
           AND
           (T3.[status] <> 'Baja' OR T3.[status] IS NULL);
 END
 GO
```

- There is no need to use `IF`.
- `status` is a reserved word, enclose it in brackets.
- Join your table with `INSERTED` table to get all the `ID`s of the rows updated.
- Join your table with `DELETED` table to get all the `ID`s where the data is not `'Baja'`.
- Filter by where `INSERTED.[status] = 'Baja' AND DELETED.[status] <> 'Baja'` to update only those rows.